# how can I ensure content delivered from the DB does not cause my table height to increase more than a certain height?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want my admin section to have a small synopsis of the detail in the main table view all.

I will have an option for admin to open each one separately so I would like to have the td height to not increase as certain fields become text heavy.

[this is what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc1io.png)

[i would prefer all height to be like this and hide additional text heavy fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JD1f.png)

I have tried max height for the td, overflow hidden, overflowy, nothing is working.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Contact List</div>
                      <div class="card-body">
                      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table`bordered table-responsive table2" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Image</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th>Breed</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                          <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>

                            </th>
                          </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>
                          <?php
                            $sql = "select * from contacts";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                          ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                            <td><img src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$row['image'] ?>" height="40"></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['age'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['breed'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                              <a href="show.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                              <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></a>
                              <a href="index.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <?php
                              }
                            }
                          ?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: How do you want the text to react in this situation? It's hard to tell from your picture. Do you want it to just display the first part and cut off the rest? Try this css for that:

`white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 90px;` or whatever you want width wise

Comment: thank you Dan. I am going to try some of this and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to expect this to be a combination of CSS `white-space`, `overflow`, and `text-overflow`.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

The `white-space` attribute will allow you to pre-format any text, whether you do this in code or in the DB itself, the `text-overflow` will allow you to set how the overflow is represented (if at all), and `overflow` will allow you to hide the excess text.

So, something like this.

```
.hideText {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Then set the class for the `description` field the same way you did for the image cell.

```
<td class="hideText"><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
```

You'll also need to set the width of the cells/column, which I'm going to assume you either know how to do or can figure that out. FYI, I'd put that in another class instead of using `style`. Classes makes it a little more easy to replicate and have in a single file/location, rather than `style`'s scattered around all your pages. I know I fought against CSS classes for years, but I finally figured creating my own were more helpful than they were annoying.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Mariam, glad I could help. If this fixed your issue, please Accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark under the voting options. You can't vote yet (you need > 15 points), but once you can, up voting would be good, too.